# how to fix libCordova.a(CDVLogger.o) ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 on mac os ionic 3 app?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to run the ionic command ionic cordova emulate ios and fails. I tried to run a clean cordova helloworld project and it runs without any problems. Below, I write to you listing the terminal with the error.

```
 /Users/frol/ionic1/platforms/ios/build/emulator/libCordova.a(CDVLogger.o)
```

ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/emulator/Live\ Hockey.app/Live\ Hockey normal x86_64
(1 failure)
(node:2641) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/frol/ionic1/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Live Hockey.xcworkspace,-scheme,Live Hockey,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/frol/ionic1/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/frol/ionic1/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
(node:2641) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

My versions
ionic - 3.19.1
cordova - 8.0.0
node - 8.9.4

When you deploy strictly followed the instructions on the website ionic and installed everything (XCode, command line). Help me

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this is because of the console plugin the new cordova-ios versions.

Try after removing the cordova console plugin.

do

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console
```

and run again.

If that does not help, try the following:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios@4.4
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! the assembly was successful! helped remove the plugin! Thank you!

Comment: is `cordova platform add ios@4.4` a mistake? latest is 4.5.4, so it should be `cordova platform add ios@4.5.4`

Comment: @jcesarmobile using ios@4.4 is exactly what does the trick here, i ran into the same problem with an old project on a new computer. Reverting to an older cordova ios plugin made it work again.

Comment: this answer is from 2018, latest cordova-ios is 6.1.0 now, you shouldn't use 4.4 anymore, you won't be able to submit apps to the app store with it

Comment: Yes, I agree -- upgrade to latest cordova-ios.